# INSERT INTO not Inserting When Declared Twice SqlLite ANDROID

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have some SQL syntax need to be executed but when I try to execute two INSERT Syntax the first is executed and the second is not Executed So Why?

**Code:**

```
db.excuteSQL("INSERT INTO `en_ahmedali`  VALUES\n" +
                    "(1, 1, 1, 'In the name of Allah, most benevolent, ever-merciful.'),\n" +
                    "(2, 1, 2, 'ALL PRAISE BE to Allah, Lord of all the worlds,'),\n" +
                    "(3, 1, 3, 'Most beneficent, ever-merciful,'),\n" +
                    "(4, 1, 4, 'King of the Day of Judgement.'),\n" +
                    "(5, 1, 5, 'You alone we worship, and to You alone turn for help.'),\n" +
                    "(6, 1, 6, 'Guide us (O Lord) to the path that is straight,'),\n" +
                    "(7, 1, 7, 'The path of those You have blessed, Not of those who have earned Your anger, nor those who have gone astray.');\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "INSERT INTO `en_ahmedali`  VALUES\n" +
                    "(6231, 114, 1, 'SAY: \"I SEEK refuge with the Lord of men,'),\n" +
                    "(6232, 114, 2, 'The King of men,'),\n" +
                    "(6233, 114, 3, 'The God of men,'),\n" +
                    "(6234, 114, 4, 'From the evil of him who breathes temptations into the minds of men,'),\n" +
                    "(6235, 114, 5, 'Who suggests evil thoughts to the hearts of men --'),\n" +
                    "(6236, 114, 6, 'From among the jinns and men.');");
```

Comment: You can't use `INSERT` like that.

Comment: It shouldn't hurt in adding one more `db.excuteSQL`.

Comment: @Rotwang You can, there's nothing wrong with the syntax here.

Comment: @Rotwang you can have multiple values sets in a single insert statement.

Comment: @Rotwang Yes I know that. That's what I told. One more call to `db.excuteSQL` with the next query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`executeSQL()` on Android can only execute on SQL statement. If you put a two statements separated by semicolon, only the first will run. You need to either combine all the values lists into one giant INSERT statement, or you need to call `executeSQL()` separately for each INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute two statements in one `execSQL` call. Separate them into two calls, either programatically using possibly the semi-colon or just manually and it will work.

Comment: The problem is that I have a .sql file that has more than 6000 Row in if it is in one insert I get the SQLite error: too many terms in the compound !

Comment: You're going to need to split the string on possibly the semi-colon. Then, inside a transaction, call `executeSQL` on each of them. Because of the transaction it should be fairly quick.

Answer (score 1):

Try an insert sintax like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTab (field1,field2,field3)
SELECT 1, 2,'3'UNION ALL
SELECT 2,3, 'v' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,4,'6'
```

I think it should work

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what SQL library you are using, but I would guess that you can only call one command per call.

Answer (score 0):

Put the inserts in separate `db.excuteSQL` statements and don't forget to commit at some time.

Comment: Ok Thanks, But is there is any way to execute them one time?

Comment: Becuase of I have a .sql file that has more than 6000 rows and putting them in one INSERT Statment will produce SQLite error: too many terms in the compound! @Gérard Binkhorst

Comment: Read that file line by line in a loop and perform the db.executeSQL followed by a commit in each cycle of that loop.

Answer (score 0):

What I reached:

- You Can't Execute More Than one statement in `db.excuteSQL()`

So there are two Options:

First, You Can Separate The Statements and Execute them Manually:

```
db.executeSQL("INSERT INTO en_ahmedali VALUES (1, 'text', 'text');");
db.executeSQL("INSERT INTO en_ahmedali VALUES (2, 'text2', 'text2');");
```

Second, You Will Use `split()` to put all statements in one Array and then Execute Them with For Loop:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO en_ahmedali VALUES (1, 'text1', 'text1');\nINSERT INTO en_ahmedali VALUES (2, 'text2', 'text2');";
String[] queries = sql.split(";\n"); //Make Sure That Each Statment is seprated with new line.

for(String query : queries){
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Thanks,